# Delphi XE2 dbExpress MySQL connection

Tags: mysql, delphi, 64-bit, delphi-xe2, dbexpress

No matter what I've tried, I couldn't make XE2 to connect to a MySQL with dbExpress. The problem has actually many faces. First, target MySQL is either 32- or 64-bits, which affects the libmysql.dll that comes with the MySQL installation, which seems to be misleading because XE2 IDE is a 32-bit application and it only accepts 32-bit DLLs. So I needed to use a 32-bit installation libmysql.dll, put it under Windows\System32 (or to the project's folder itself), and then set the Target compile platform to 32-bit in my project (so that it won't try to use 64-bit dbxmys.dll, just in case), still with no luck. All the combinations I tried resulted with this error: "DBX Error: Driver could not be properly initialized. Client library may be missing......."

Anyone who's able to make XE2 dbExpress connect to a MySQL server? I need your help. Thanks in advance.

Windows 7 64-bit (dev platform with XE2), MySQL 5.5.16 32-bit (installed on a remote XP 32-bit) / MySQL 5.1.54 64-bit (installed on a remote XP x64) (tried with both, by using their libmysql.dlls)

Answer (score 2):

the answer to your question is simple, install your mysql and copy libmysql.dll from your mysql bin as shown eg.(C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin) and then go to the xe2 directory and open the bin too eg (C:\Program Files\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\9.0\bin) and paste it there over running the already libmysql.dll in it.

Answer (score 1):

As it seems you have x64 Windows, then you should put x32 `libmysql.dll` not into `Windows\System32`, but into `Windows\SysWOW64`. Or you can put x32 `libmysql.dll` into `XE2\Bin` folder.

If you will build x64 application, then x64 `libmysql.dll` you should put into `Windows\System32` or into your EXE folder.

Comment: I'd read a post stating the opposite about Windows\System32 and Windows\SysWOW64 but I've tried both ways anyway. Still same error. I even tried both dbxmys.dll and libmysql.dll into project's exe folder (which should be the first place to look for DLLs). It looks like there's something else I'm missing here. I've noticed a TSQLConnection parameter called VendorLibWin64 in Data Explorer->Modify Connection->Advanced window which you couldn't see in Object Inspector normally (along with VendorLib which you can access thru Object Inspector), and tried to also set it manually with no avail again

Comment: That is hard to say, what you are doing wrong. Could you summarize - bitness of your windows, application, libmysql.dll. Where and what you are puting. That will help to see a mistake or confirm that the setup is right, but dbExpress fails.

Comment: Let me get this straight: You are saying, when running in 64-bit put the 64-bit dll in system32, when running in 32-bit mode, put the 32 bit dll in sysWOW64. That makes little sense to me. The other way round sounds much more sensible.

Comment: No, i am saying: 64bit mode - x64 dll -> system32, x32 dll -> SysWOW64. 32bit mode - x32 dll -> system32. That is the story ...

Comment: Guys, I've tried both ways and it didn't work. The problems seems to be lying in somewhere else. I wonder if anyone could actually make this work. By the way, my config was like this, Windows 7 64-bit, MySQL 5.5.16 32-bit (installed on a remote XP 32-bit) / MySQL 5.1.54 64-bit (installed on a remote XP x64) (tried with both, by using their libmysql.dlls)

Answer (score 1):

The answer for this question is found at [WiltonSoftware.com](http://wiltonsoftware.com/posts/view/getting-embarcadero-dbexpress-mysql-working-dbx-error-driver-not-initialized).

What I did was:

1. I downloaded the a zip file containing libmysql.dll version 5.1.59
2. I created the folder C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector 5.1.59\lib
3. I copied the DLL to the just created folder
4. I added that folder in the Windows Path environment variable

It worked fine to me!

Comment: +1 Or you could just create new folder into any of system folders, already set with Windows Path ;) But generally this isn't bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but I hope it helps:

1. Install the latest Updates for Delphi XE2
2. Install SQL Server 2008 native client
3. Uninstall everything old like SQL Server Express 2005 (if installed)

I was not able to pinpoint the exact reason why this works. Could be the usage of sqlncli.dll instead of oledb.dll.

Answer (score 0):

Hrmm, apparently the question I asked was a bug in XE2 and supposedly fixed with Update 1 http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Release_Notes_for_XE2#Please_Install_XE2_Update_1

I'll try and see if it really fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The only version works with XE2 was 5.1.54 i had the same problem and being solved by this